# AngularJS : Losing scope in directive after promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

I am actually having a big problem in my angular application.

I have a Factory which does an http request to get the spoolers and returns a promise.

```
Spooler.prototype.load = function () {
    var self = this;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/spooler/' + this.id + '/load')
        .success(function(data) {
            self.statistics = data.statistics;
            deferred.resolve(self);
        })
        .error(function(err, code) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        $log.error(err, code);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

The problem happens in my controller when I use the "then()" keyword, the values inside this then will be passed to a directive as follow:

```
$scope.load = function(){
        spooler.load().then(
            function(dataSpooler){
                $scope.spooler = dataSpooler;
                $scope.custom = 4; // example of random var inside then()
            }
            function() {
                $scope.dataFail = 'error error' ;
            }
        );
    }
```

When I log the variable custom in the view, everything is good, I see '4'.
However, the problem happens when i use this variable in my directive as follow:

```
<highchart-pie items="custom"></highchart-pie>
```

Here is the directive's code:

```
 .directive('highchartPie', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
           items : '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        },

        template: '<div style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto;">not working</div>', //
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
                console.log(scope); // i can see the item value 4
                console.log(scope.items); !!! undefined !!!
                link function is actually way bigger and renders the element to the template (useless to be shown)
        }
    }
```

Here is my conclusion, when I assign

```
$scope.custom = 4;
```

Inside the then() function, it does not work because the directive probably doesnt receive the values on time (even tho in the link function in the directive the log sees it).

If I declare $scope.custom = 4; at the top of the controller before the then() method, every works smoothly  ...

An idea anyone ? Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: No need to create a new promise to use `$http`...it returns a promise already...considered an anti-pattern. Just return `$http`

Comment: You can't see `scope.custom` inside your directive because you don't have any isolated scopes called `custom`, you should use `scope.items` to see the value

Comment: Also, I am using highcharts as well and inside my directive's link function, I have a `$watch` on `items` and inside that watch lies all the highchart code, this way, everytime the data (items) changes, the chart get's rendered again with the new dataset. Hope this helps

Comment: Here is the Plnkr of the current problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/0VmiTSRqikaB37aHD8l1?p=preview Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

first way,

```
$scope.load = function(){
        return spooler.load().then(
            function(dataSpooler){
                $scope.spooler = dataSpooler;
                $scope.custom = 4; // example of random var inside then()
            }
            function() {
                $scope.dataFail = 'error error' ;
            }
        );
    }
```

but not the best way perhaps,

```
$scope.load = spooler.load;
```

then,

```
$scope.load().then(
                function(dataSpooler){
                    $scope.spooler = dataSpooler;
                    $scope.custom = 4; // example of random var inside then()
                }
                function() {
                    $scope.dataFail = 'error error' ;
                }
            );
```

Comment: Don't make people play `spot the difference`... give a proper explanation as to what is different...and also why it would help

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log runs before the promise is resolved, and that's why the items are undefined. As @Razvan Balosin mentions in his comment, you'll have to $watch the items array(so that when you finally get the data Angular knows about the change, and you can do whatever you need to do with the data)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest you to do:

```
link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
 scope.$watch('film',function(item){
   // if there is any data in film, render chart
   if(item) {
    console.log("Scope: " , scope);
    console.log("Film:", scope.film); // works now
   }
  })
}
```

And the modified [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A6BF10UCjO9vJrPSNzQB?p=preview)